# Prove that $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}) - \ln2$ is odd

Tags: logarithms, alternative-proof

I know that a function is odd when
$$f(-x) = -f(x)$$
Therefore I can say that if for a function $$-f(x) + f(x) = f(-x) + f(x) = 0$$

Then the function is odd!

I tried to use this *trick* to prove that $f(x) = \ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right) - \ln2$ is odd.

However, I would want to prove directly that $$f(-x) = -f(x)$$
In other words, I want to solve $$\ln\left(-x+\sqrt{(-x)^2 + 4}\right) - \ln2$$
and to come at the end to this:
$$-\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right) + \ln2$$

**This was my approach:**
$$\ln\left(-x+\sqrt{(-x)^2 + 4}\right) - \ln2$$
$$\ln\left(-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right) - \ln2$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2}\right)$$
$$\ln\left(\left(\frac{2}{-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}}\right)^{-1}\right)$$
$$-\ln\left(\frac{2}{-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}}\right)$$

---

Here I got stuck. I want to get to $-\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right) + \ln2$ but if I use $\ln\left(\frac ab\right) = \ln a - \ln b$ then I will get back to $f(-x)$ and not to $-f(x)$.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Rationalise the denominator of the fraction inside the ln.

I.e. multiply top and bottom by $x+\sqrt{x^2+4}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right)\left(-x+\sqrt{x^2 + 4}\right)=4=2\cdot2$$ so that, taking the logarithm,

$$f(x)+f(-x)=0.$$

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way to continue my approach like @jugglingmike hinted.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}-x}=\frac{2(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)}4$$

Answer (score 3):

A faster approach. If we set $f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}\right)$ and $x=2\sinh\theta$ we have 
$$f(2\sinh\theta) = \log\left(\frac{2\sinh\theta+2\cosh\theta}{2}\right) = \log(e^\theta) = \theta $$
and since $\theta\mapsto 2\sinh\theta$ is a bijective odd function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$,
$$ f(-x) = -f(x) $$
readily follows. That also implies $f(x) = \text{arcsinh}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: This is too complicated for me...

Comment: That is really elegant...and also maddening when professors just pull a sinh out of thin air. How did you know to do so?

Comment: @KingZoingo: the substitution $x=2\sinh\theta$ simplifies $x+\sqrt{x^2+4}$ by a lot. That is really useful also in finding $$\int \log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\,dx, $$ for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It  simply means
\begin{align}
&\ln(-x+\sqrt{x^2+4})-\ln2=-\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})+\ln2\\
\iff &\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+4})+\ln(-x+\sqrt{x^2+4})=2\ln 2\\
\iff&\ln[(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x)]=\ln4\\
\iff &(\sqrt{x^2+4}+x)(\sqrt{x^2+4}-x)=4.
\end{align}

Comment: I wanted to know if there's a way to continue my approach like @jugglingmike hinted.